# LUKS change encryption key

Tags: encryption, disk, change-password

I found on this forum some very interesting content for problem that I have, but I don't found answer for my question.

To change encryption password I can use command:

```
cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/sda2
```

... and that works. But how to encrypt /dev/sda2 partition again with new password?

If my old password is compromised and I only change password, stored data is encrypted with old password not with new.

Answer (score 2):

The LUKS partition itself is not encrypted with your password: it is encrypted with a strong "**master key**" randomly calculated upon volume creation. Your old and new passwords only serve to encrypt the "master key". Unfortunately both passwords and the "master key" as often referred to as "keys" hence your (and others') confusion.

When in the old days cryptsetup did not rely on LUKS, every time you changed your cryptsetup password the entire disk would have to be re-encrypted!

Nowdays you only have to change your master key if someone also gains physical or administrative access to the encrypted device while the password is valid.

p.s. if not relying on temporary storage but having free space, the LUKS master key may be "changed" by shrinking a LUKS volume via "cryptsetup resize", creating another volume, moving data, deleting the first volume and expanding the second volume.